# Data not fetch in sub report of crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have some problem on fetching data in sub report. In crystal report data fetch in proper manner but when i click on sub report it show "No valid report source is available"

```
protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
            ComplaintTrackingSystem.Reports.Datas dss = new Reports.Datas();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // Just set the name of data table
            DataSet ds;
            Hashtable ObjParameters = new Hashtable();
            BusinessLogicLayer ObjBusiness = new BusinessLogicLayer();
            ObjParameters.Add("@From", dateFrom.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
            ObjParameters.Add("@To", dateTo.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString());
            ds = ObjBusiness.SPDataSet(ObjParameters, "ReportForAverageCompt");
            dt.TableName = "Crystal Report Example";
            dt = ds.Tables[0]; //This function is located below this function
            dss.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            // Your .rpt file path will be below
            rptDoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../Reports/AverageReport.rpt"));
            //set dataset to the report viewer.
            rptDoc.SetDataSource(dss);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
            Session["Report"] = rptDoc;
            ComplaintTrackingSystem.Reports.Datas dssNew = new Reports.Datas();
            ds.Clear();
            ds = ObjBusiness.SPDataSet(ObjParameters, "ReportForResolvedCompt");
            dt.TableName = "Crystal Report";
            dt = ds.Tables[0]; //This function is located below this function
            dssNew.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            //set dataset to the report viewer.
            rptDoc.Subreports["AdminReport.rpt"].SetDataSource(dssNew);
            rptDoc.Refresh();
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;

        }
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Any error not shown... It is not fetch the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening in the viewer, right?  If so, the error could be the result of the viewer not being able to find the report in session.  Check out the thread "[No valid report source is available. in asp.net sap crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450051/no-valid-report-source-is-available-in-asp-net-sap-crystal-report)".